# Allow only traffic from Front End to ADF front door

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have two app services one running the front end and one running the back end (REST API)
Both app services have an instance of Front-Door and WAF in front of them.

Now I would like to create a custom rule on the backend FD to make sure it only allows traffic from the front end. This is to avoid a malicious user can use postman to access APIs or create robots

I have tried to create a custom rule whitelisting the front-end IP address but it is not working. (requests are blocked).

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "it is not working", what do you mean? Traffic still gets in even though rule is in place? Or no traffic gets in?

Comment: @juunas requests are blocked even if the ip addresses of the front-end app services have been listed

Comment: So the request is initiated from inside the App Service back-end and not from browser front-end? Is there any VNET integrations?

Comment: @juunas
Browser (httppost) --> FD- FrontEnd --> front-end app service  --> back end FD - Backend

Comment: Ok and seems those Frontdoor instances are different :\ That's quite weird. Are you able to share screenshots of configurations (with URLs etc. hidden)?

Comment: @juunas there are two front door instances. Once for the back end and one for the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the front door, there were no direct firewall blocks, such as Application Gateway or app services. We should be restricted via the IP restriction [rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction) under firewall blocking using WAF.

In this case, we need to restrict the traffic from the backend [App Services side] by setting up inbound and outbound [traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/network-secure-outbound-traffic-azure-firewall) permissions via VNet.

The front door always routes traffic to the appropriate backends; if an end point is unavailable, it checks failover endpoints. If those are not available or reachable, the error "Services are not available, such as" will be displayed.

[image]

NOTE: Find reference links for more information.